# DBD::mysql: mysql.so: undefined symbol: net_buffer_length

Tags: perl

My script worked perfectly fine under Centos 6.5 and Mysql.

I recently moved to a new server with Centos 7 and MariaDB.

When I run the script, I get a message:

`install_driver(mysql) failed:
Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' for module DBD::mysql: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so: undefined symbol: net_buffer_length at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 190, <DATA> line 855.  at (eval 55) line 3.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 55) line 3, <DATA> line 855.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected`

I have installed perl-DBD-MySQL and other required modules.

```
#!/usr/bin/perlml

use lib '/usr/lib/perl5';
use 5.008;
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use File::Path qw(make_path);
use IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress qw(:all) ;
use IO::File;
use PHP::Functions::Mail qw(mail);
use LWP::Simple;
use Parse::CSV;
use DBI();
use XML::Smart;
use Time::Piece;
use Data::Dumper;   #for debugging purposes only
```

I am not sure what else to look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recent change to the maria db libraries produces this error; DBD::mysql version 4.046_01 has a fix, but it is not yet in a non-development version.

You can install it with:

```
cpan MICHIELB/DBD-mysql-4.046_01.tar.gz
```